# GCP SQL Server - Grant & Revoke User

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I'm still new to GCP. I have a SQL Server. And I have 2 users in it. first one is 'sqlserver' (which is default from GCP) and 'userA' (this is the new account)

I have so many databases, and I want 'sqlserver' account is the only one who can access everything. But for 'userA', I want it only can access 1 database (lets say DatabaseA)

I have tried to revoke select, deny select, revoke all. But userA still can query to another databases.

Any solution? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users you create using GCP SQL Server are created as member of **CustomerDbRootRole** role, and have the same permissions of **sqlserver** user.

You can change the permissions of any user by using the [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command.

For example you can remove your user from **CustomerDbRootRole** with the following script:

```
  ALTER ROLE CustomerDbRootRole DROP MEMBER YourUser;
```

Also I suggest you to check all the YourUser's permissions with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DB
    ,P.name   AS Database_Principal
    ,P2.name  AS Ruolo
    ,P.type_desc
    ,P.create_date
FROM
    sys.database_principals P 
    INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members R ON R.member_principal_id = P.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals P2  ON P2.principal_id = R.role_principal_id 
WHERE
     P.[name] IN ('YourUser')
ORDER BY
     P.[name]
```

After you can revoke the all unnecessary permissions with ALTER ROLE like above.

In your case, if you want to give only the read permissions on a single database to a specific user I recommend:

1- Create a user:

```
USE [YourDB]
GO

CREATE USER [YourUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

2- Add your user xxx into **db_datareader** role:

```
USE [YourDB]
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [YourUser]
GO
```

Comment: Did this answer help?

Comment: are you experiencing the same problem?

Comment: This does not work. The `ALTER ROLE` and `CREATE USER` commands fail due to missing permissions of the `CustomerDbRootRole`. In addition, the permission listing oddly returns nothing. So it seems to me that the cat bites its own tail and there is no way out of the `CustomerDbRootRole`.